# Play Framework: Problems migrating from version 2.3.x to 2.4.1

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I'm migrating my Play application from version 2.3.8 to version 2.4.1... and I'm encountering some problems with JSON.

The main issue is that now `obj \ key` returns a `JsLookupResult` and statements like `Json.arr(obj \ key, 1)` fail because `Json.arr` expects a `JsValueWrapper`.

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are certain that `\` will not fail, you can just call `.get` on it, as you would an `Option`.

`Json.arr( (obj \ key).get, 1)`

Needless to say, there are other operands like `getOrElse`that can provide a default value in case `obj` has no `key`.

Comment: Like `.get` on `Option` or with `Try`, this is quite unsafe with `JsLookupResult`.